# Integration using partial decomposition

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate $$ \ \int \frac{x}{(x-1)(x+1)^2} \ \ dx \ . $$
I have equated x = A(x+1)(x-1) + B(X+1)(x+1) + C(x+1)(x+1)
to get x = x^2(A + C) + x(B + 2C) + (-A - B + C)
After equating the coefficients, you get (Eqn 1) A + C = 0 (Eqn 2) B + 2C = 1 (Eqn 3) -A + B + C = 0.
However this system of equations doesn't have a unique solution, so how do I go about solving it from here?

Comment: Is it $x/((x-1)(x+1)^2)$?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take more care with the equations.

The equation is $x=\left( x-1\right) \,C+\left( x-1\right) \,\left( x+1\right) \,B+{\left( x+1\right) }^{2}\,A$, which results in three equations $A-C-B = 0$, $C+2A=1$, $A+B = 0$. These have the unique solution $A=\frac{1}{4}$, $B=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $C= \frac{1}{2}$.

That is,
$\frac{x}{(x-1)(x+1)^2} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} $

Answer (score 1):

You can make life somewhat easier on yourself by *not* multiplying out the factors.  The decomposition is

$$\frac{A}{x-1} \ + \ \frac{B}{x+1} \ + \ \frac{C}{(x+1)^2} \ , $$

so the numerator, which must equal $ \ x \ $ , is

$$A (x+1)^2 \ + \ B (x-1)(x + 1 ) \ + \ C (x-1) \ . $$

Setting $ \ x = -1 \ $ gives  $ \ C \cdot (-2) = -1 \ $ and putting $ \ x = 1 \ $ yields $ \ A \cdot 2^2 = 1 \ . $  To obtain $ \ B \ $ , choose any other value for $ \ x \ $ , say, $ \ x = 0 \ $ , insert your results for $ \ A \ $ and  $ \ C \ $ and solve the remaining equation

$$ \frac{1}{4} \cdot 1^2 \ + \ B \cdot (-1) \cdot 1 \ + \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot (-1) \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ B \ = \ -\frac{1}{4} \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int{{\rm d}x \over \left(x - 1\right)\left(\mu x + 1\right)} 
&=
\mu^{-1}\int{{\rm d}x \over \left(x - 1\right)\left(x + \mu^{-1}\right)} 
=
{\mu \over \mu + 1}
\int\left({1 \over x - 1} + {1 \over x + \mu^{-1}}\right)\,{\rm d}x 
\\[3mm]&=
{\mu \over \mu + 1}
\ln\left(x - 1 \over x + \mu^{-1}\right)
\end{align}

In both members, multiply by $-1$ and derivates respect $\mu$:
$$
\int{x \over \left(x - 1\right)\left(\mu x + 1\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x 
=
-\,{1 \over \left(\mu + 1\right)^{2}}
\ln\left(x - 1 \over x + \mu^{-1}\right)
+
{\mu \over \mu +1}\,
{-\mu^{-2} \over x + \mu^{-1}}
$$

Set $\mu = 1$:
$$
\int{x \over \left(x - 1\right)\left({\bf 1}\times x + 1\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x 
=
-\,{1 \over \left({\bf 1} + 1\right)^{2}}
\ln\left(x - 1 \over x + {\bf 1}^{-1}\right)
+
{{\bf 1} \over {\bf 1} +1}\,
{-{\bf 1}^{-2} \over x + {\bf 1}^{-1}}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\int{x \over \left(x - 1\right)\left(x + 1\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x 
=
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ln\left(x - 1 \over x + 1\right)
-
{1 \over 2\left(x + 1\right)}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$